# AKS: How to get rid of load balancer?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

When you create an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) it creates by default a load balancer and a networking set to access it. It creates it in a separate resource group.

We are however not interested at all in this load balancer, as we are going to use our own load balancer/Ingress configured within Kubernetes itself.

Question: How can we avoid this Load balancer from Azure to be generated all the time when we generate the cluster?

Comment: How do you create the AKS? Terraform\ARM\ Manually ?

Comment: what is the use case?

Answer (score 2):

Was discussed in [AKS Creation Without Public Load Balancer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11233) github issue with afterward explanation

> It is possible the SLB IP is just for egress.
>
> Let me try to clarify.
>
> AKS with Basic Load Balancer
>
> You can create it by passing the load balancer sku parameter Has
>   implicit Egress (you won't see a public IP, although it is there on
>   the Azure infrastructure) You can create private services accessible
>   only through private IPs using the internal annotation.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb AKS with
>   Standard Load Balancer
>
> Used by default on latest clientes, or explicitly by using the same
>   parameter as above Has only explicit egress, which means if there
>   isn't an egress IP the cluster won't have egress and will be broken.
>   This is like the gateway to the internet IP. You can control,
>   pre-create or change this IP (or have more than one) You can create
>   private services accessible through private IPs using the internal
>   annotation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb In
>   some cases, enterprises might have egress defined via UDRs through a
>   firewall etc. In which case that egress IP will not be used, and will
>   be effectively not needed. But as of now it will be needed at create
>   time as we don't know the egress path defined. We are no working on a
>   UDR outbound type for SLB that will allow users to confirm they have
>   egress through UDRs and in this case the SLB won't be created with a
>   Public IP for egress

Like @Sajeetharan asked- what is the use case?
Also how is it mandatory for you to use AKS? Maybe the same you can  easier resolve just regular with kubeadm cluster?

[Deploying a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using kubeadm](https://blog.jreypo.io/containers/microsoft/azure/cloud/cloud-native/devops/deploying-a-kubernetes-cluster-in-azure-using-kubeadm/)

Comment: I am also creating a AKS with Terraform and would like to only use the NGINX ingress controller